# Add autocomplete to CKEditorUploadingWidget

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form that uses CKEditorUploadingWidget from the ckeditor_uploader package. The form class is called TemplateMesForm and contains a CharField named temp_html.

```
from ckeditor_uploader.widgets import CKEditorUploadingWidget 
class TemplateMesForm(forms.RequestForm):
temp_html = forms.CharField(label='Html:'), widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
```

I would like to add autocomplete to the temp_html field, but I'm unsure how to do so. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the [**`attrs=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) of the widget:

```
from ckeditor_uploader.widgets import CKEditorUploadingWidget


class TemplateMesForm(forms.RequestForm):
    temp_html = forms.CharField(
        label='Html:',
        widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget(attrs={'autocomplete': True}),
    )
```

Comment: I need the autocomplete to pull the list of items from a database table based on matches. I plan to implement this in a specific view, but I don't understand how to connect this view to the temp_html form field. Is it possible to specify the path to this view in the form field, or is there another way to implement this?